# Unable to open excel with Roo or Spreadsheet Gems

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet

When I try this with `roo gem`:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'roo'
   => true
irb(main):002:0> oo = Excel.new("C:/Users/Abash/Desktop/test1.xls")

**NameError: uninitialized constant Excel** from (irb):2 
from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

When I try this with `spreadsheet gem`:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'spreadsheet'
   => true
   irb(main):002:0>Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
   => "UTF-8"
   irb(main):003:0> book = Spreadsheet.open 'C:/Users/Abash/Desktop/test1.xls'

**Errno::EACCES: Permission denied** - C:/Users/Abash/Desktop/test1.xls
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.8.2/lib/spreadsheet.rb:69:in `initialize'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.8.2/lib/spreadsheet.rb:69:in `open'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.8.2/lib/spreadsheet.rb:69:in `open'
from (irb):3
from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Can somebody show me a work around for these errors?

Comment: You shouldn't open this file in MS Excel when you run your script. That's why it says `Permission denied` in `spreadsheet` case. And in the first case use `Roo::Excel.new`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using ruby 1.9 or above version. In such a case,you need to specify the gem while creating a new instance.

```
 require 'roo'

 s =Roo::Excel.new("myspreadsheet.xls")       

 s =Roo::Excelx.new("myspreadsheet.xlsx")
```